# How to rank search results by alphabetical order (Django 2.1)

Tags: django

I have code for a search engine and a button that ranks by alphabetical order, but I can't get them to work together. 
Code for search engine:

```
def query_search(request):
    articles = cross_currents.objects.all()
    search_term = ''
    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        search_term = request.GET['keyword']
        articles = articles.annotate(similarity=Greatest(TrigramSimilarity('Title', search_term), TrigramSimilarity('Content', search_term))).filter(similarity__gte=0.03).order_by('-similarity')
        if 'a-z' in request.GET:
            articles = articles.order_by('Title')
```

Code for button that ranks posts by alphabetical order:

```
<a href="?a-z=True" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-{% if 'a-z' in request.GET %}success{% else %}secondary{% endif %}">A-Z</a>
```

The button ranks all posts by alphabetical order rather than only ranking the posts in the search results. It's probably because I am not combining the value of `request.GET` generated by the button and the value generated by the keyword entered into the search engine. How can I edit the code so that the button only ranks the posts in the search results?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    if request.GET.get('a-z') == 'True':
        articles = articles.order_by('Title')
```

You also need to do the same for `keyword`. `request.GET` is a dictionary. You can only use `in` with lists.